# Trouble installing BigCommerce Stencil-CLI on my Mac

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, bigcommerce

I am trying to install the Stencil-CLI in terminal, but it keeps hanging up.
This last time I got the error message(s):

npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/bigcommerce/browser-sync.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

I followed these instructions from their docs:

## Install Node Version Manager (nvm)

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash

## Install Stencil CLI supported version of Node.js

nvm install 8.16

## Switch to Stencil CLI supported version of Node.js:

nvm use 8.16

## Install Stencil CLI

npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli

Also I used this additional command to reset terminal to use nvm: source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

Any insight into what is going on is appreciated. Do I need to set up a remote repository on my machine first?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running the following command?

`git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

This sounds like you might be getting blocked by network rules or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. Tried running that command then npm global install. Still just hanging. I read somewhere that you need xCode to be installed? I am downloading that now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. But overcame with these steps.

- First manually download the stencil-cli from github and save it in local directory.
- Delete old stencil related files if exists. In my case those are in AppData\Roaming\npm. 
  (better if you can delete npm folder itself).
- then install it with this command. `npm i -g folder\Path\to\downloaded\stencil\folder`
- Done..!!